# Backbone.js - Correct event to bind when creating a model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a Backbone view that binds to the **add** event of a **notes** collection like this (using CoffeeScript):

```
    initialize: () ->
      @options.notes.bind('add', @noteAdded)
```

And here's the **noteAdded** method and also the **addOneNote** method that is called to add the recently created note to the DOM:

```
    addOneNote: (note) =>
      view = new CrmBliss.Views.Consultants.NoteView({model: note})
      @$(".past_notes").prepend view.render().el

    noteAdded: (model, response) =>
      console.debug 'model', model.toJSON()
      @addOneNote(model)
```

Finally, here's how I call the the **create** method on the collection:

```
    saveNote: (e) =>
      id = @model.get('id') 
      body = @$('.note-body').val()

      @options.notes.create({ body: body, consultant_id: id })
```

I expected that the **noteAdded** would get called with the model that reflects what was added on the database. There are some fields that are returned for the model, that are not inserted by the client, but rather calculated by the server. Namely, **created_at** and **user_name** are methods that will be returned by the server, but that the client isn't aware of before a fetch from the server.

So when I try to render the following (eco) template:

```
    <div class="note">
      <span class="date"><%= @created_at %></span>
      by
      <span class="taker"><%= @user_name %></span>
      <div class="note_body">
        <%= @body %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Only the body is rendered (because the object used to create the note already had the body attribute).

If I change my **noteAdded** method to wait a bit before inserting the note, it works:

```
  noteAdded: (model, response) =>
    console.debug 'note before', model.toJSON()
    console.debug 'model', model
    attrShow = =>
      console.debug 'after time', model.toJSON()
      @addOneNote(model)
    setTimeout(attrShow, 1000)
```

Which makes me thing that I am obviously binding to the wrong event, and that I should bind to an event that is called when the model is loaded from the server.

Which event should I bind to that, when called, has the correct (and final) model properties?

Comment: Hi, it's hard to answer your question because this is probably a code smell due to a bad design decision. And, I think the problem reside in the way you instantiate your new model, rather than in the way you create a view from this model. So, how do you create new model? (from which view, after which event, and what's the code).

Comment: In theory, the best way may be to wait until your model is ready before inserting it into your collection. Then the `add` event would work like you'd expect.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias how do I know if a model is ready?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I am not adding my model to the collection. I am instead creating a new model and also binding to the `add` event on the collection.

Comment: If you listen to the `add` event on a collection, then you add the new model to the collection at some point. What you want then is to only add it after the model has finished `fetch`ing data from the server.